# Signed Applet trying to copy .jar file from Server URL to local filesystem. Works, but .jar gets corrupted

Tags: java, file, applet, download, signed

I'm trying to write an applet that installs files to the users system for use with an local Java mapping utility. I have a jar file with the main method for my Java utility along with a couple of other files that are used with my local mapping utility.

I use the following method from the Apache commons File-IO: [Documentation here](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile%28java.net.URL,%20java.io.File%29)

Everything *seemingly* works fine. The file is copied upon runnning the Applet (the user is prompted with a warning requesting the permissions) and everything seems fine at this point.

When the file is run, however, the .jar gets corrupted and I literally watch as the file size goes from 250 kB to 0 right after it is run. 
What would cause such behavior? I try extracting the archive and looking at the contents...all my classes seem to be there. What would cause a .jar to "self destruct" like this?

Also, if I just download the file normally. It works fine. It only corrupts like this when I download from the signed applet.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: what happens if you ONLY download the jar using the code, and then manually run the jar from the command line?

Comment: Try to add this at the initialization of the applet : System.setSecurityManager(null);